# Relatively positioned child covers parent outline

Tags: html, css

I'm running into the following issue.  A relatively positioned child inside a parent element that can receive tab focus **overflows** the parent div slightly, and hides some of the parent's tab focus outline.  On Chrome, this outline is partially hidden, and on IE, this outline is completely hidden by the child element.

See this attached JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/55h4wtrc/7/.

```css
.parent {
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.child {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent' tabindex='0'>
  <div class='child'>text</div>
</div>

<div class='parent' tabindex='0'>
  <div class='child'>text</div>
</div>

<div class='parent' tabindex='0'>
  <div class='child'>text</div>
</div>
```

Removing the CSS line `position: relative;` from the `.child` fixes this buggy behavior.

In my case, i need the outline to be completely visible, and I also need the child element to be relatively positioned.  I also need the child element to have a higher z-index than its parent, so no z-index tricks to fix this bug will work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't spot a difference in Firefox 58.0.2

You could try using border-box: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }`.

Comment: this is really interesenting. Setting the border to none (maybe on the parent's focus, `.parent:focus > .child{ border:none;}` + the background to transparent on the child also "fixes" the issue, but I'd assume your actual use case won't allow for that. Really interested on knowing what's causing this behaviour. I feel like position:relative with no top/left/bottom/right declarations shouldn't cause any change at all (besides the anchoring for absolute positioned childs), but it seems it's does :s

Comment: Right... I realized that too @FacundoCorradini.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to show the effect you're seeing?

Comment: In chrome the outline is completely visible, what is overflowing what?

Comment: It's not actually completely visible.  Try toggling the `position: relative` on and off, you should see a visual difference

Comment: What browser version are you using?

Comment: I can't see what you are talking about on any browser. No issue on FF, everything seems normal on Chrome, can't see in IE..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Reason

From the [CSS Basic User Interface Level 3 specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-3/#outline-props):

> 1. Outlines do not take up space.

and later

> The stacking of the rendering of these outlines is explicitly left up to implementations to provide a better user experience per platform. [...]

This means that browsers are pretty free in rendering outlines. If one renders them within the boundaries of an element in question, they might be covered by children.

### Mitigation

You can apply custom styling to the outline, using the `outline` and `outline-offset` properties to set color, style and position manually during focus, as shown in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55h4wtrc/43/), e.g.

```
.parent:focus {
  outline: hotpink dashed 2px;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}
```

If this doesn't work out, you might as well use a completely different tool, such as `box-shadow`, as shown in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/55h4wtrc/45/), e.g.

```
.parent:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px teal;
}
```

Comment: If the purpose is keyboard navigation, then outline is fairly critical.